# what is the meaning of 'stingo' here?

Tags: word-meaning

> Outside, an hour later, Quoyle at his fire, the aunt taking things out
>   of the food box; eggs, a crushed bag of bread, butter, jam. Sunshine
>   crowded against the aunt, her hands following, seizing packets. The
>   child unwrapped the butter, the aunt spread it with a piece of broken
>   wood for a knife, stirred the shivering eggs in the pan. The bread
>   heel for the old dog. Bunny at the landwash casting peckled stones. As
>   each struck, foaming lips closed over it. They sat beside the fire.
>   The smoky **stingo** like an offering from some stone altar, the aunt
>   thought, watched the smolder melt into the sky. Bunny and Sunshine
>   leaned against Quoyle. Bunny ate a slice of bread rolled up, the jelly
>   poised at the end like the eye of a toaster oven, watched the smoke
>   gyre. “Dad. Why does smoke twist around?”

*The Shipping News by Annie Proulx*

I added more text

I looked up the dictionary and **stingo** means **strong ale** or **zest** but these meanings don't seem make sense here. Are there any other meanings? 
It looks like it's the **stingo** that watches the smolder.

Comment: Why can't a **strong beer** (placed on a rock) look like **an offering on a stone altar** especially at the end of the day around a campfire?

Comment: There was a dark beer sold in the US under the brand name *Stingo*, as I recall.  But there's not enough context supplied here to say.

Comment: But what is the subject of **watched** here? Is there a missing "as she"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stingo is a strong beer that is often described as having a smoky flavor.

So, despite what is an apparent clumsy sentence, as pointed out in the comments, smoky stingo is referring beer.

It does not mean that it is being heated, but the author is simply juxtaposing a quality of the beer with the spiraling smoke from Quoyle's fire.